# Segmentation Fault Swift 2 App

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, segmentation-fault

I just converted my project to Swift 2, an converted the entire code to the new syntax. However, I'm getting Segmentation Fault error when I try to build the app. Below is build output.

```
CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/Event.swift
    cd /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/SpeakerDetailsViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/AboutUsViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/AttendeeCell.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/ConfirmNewProfileImageViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/SurveyViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/NotificationsTableViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/SponsorWebsiteViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/FavoritesTableViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/AgendaViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/AppDelegate.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/Sponsor.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/CustomNavController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/StickyNotification.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/MoreInfoViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/TravelVC.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/SponsorsTableViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/SpeakerCell.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/BasicNavController.swift -primary-file /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/Event.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/PublicConstants.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/Attendee.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/Conference.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/ConfInfoViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/DBQuestion.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/TravelBusiness.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/MyAcountPrefsTableViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/PeopleViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/EventDetailsViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/SideMenuTableVC.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/Speaker.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/NotificationManager.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/QRViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/ConfListTableViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/DiscussionBoard.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/ENSideMenu.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/Session.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/QRWebViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/ManTabBarController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/ObjectManager.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/ColoredSegmentButton.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/DBManager.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/ENSideMenuNavigationController.swift -target x86_64-apple-ios8.0 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk -I /Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI -F /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf -F /Users/satre/Downloads/parse-library-1 -enable-testing -g -import-objc-header /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf-Bridging-Header.h -module-cache-path /Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -D COCOAPODS -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Intermediates/STSI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/STSI.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Intermediates/STSI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/STSI.build/STSI-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Intermediates/STSI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/STSI.build/STSI-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Intermediates/STSI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/STSI.build/STSI-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Intermediates/STSI.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Intermediates/STSI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/STSI.build/STSI-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Intermediates/STSI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/STSI.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Intermediates/STSI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/STSI.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc -working-directory/Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI -emit-module-doc-path /Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Intermediates/STSI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/STSI.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Event~partial.swiftdoc -Onone -module-name STSI -emit-module-path /Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Intermediates/STSI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/STSI.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Event~partial.swiftmodule -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Intermediates/STSI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/STSI.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Event.dia -emit-dependencies-path /Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Intermediates/STSI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/STSI.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Event.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Intermediates/STSI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/STSI.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Event.swiftdeps -o /Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Intermediates/STSI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/STSI.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Event.o

0  swift                    0x000000010cc2cedb llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 43
1  swift                    0x000000010cc2d61b SignalHandler(int) + 379
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff91811f1a _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff54ec0d50 _sigtramp + 3278564944
4  swift                    0x000000010b4038d5 swift::Type::transform(std::__1::function<swift::Type (swift::Type)> const&) const + 53
5  swift                    0x000000010b245086 swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::simplifyType(swift::Type, llvm::SmallPtrSet<swift::TypeVariableType*, 16u>&) + 54
6  swift                    0x000000010b266cba swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::diagnoseFailureForExpr(swift::Expr*) + 2362
7  swift                    0x000000010b2693cf swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::salvage(llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::constraints::Solution>&, swift::Expr*) + 143
8  swift                    0x000000010b2c3bfc swift::TypeChecker::solveForExpression(swift::Expr*&, swift::DeclContext*, swift::Type, swift::FreeTypeVariableBinding, swift::ExprTypeCheckListener*, swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem&, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::constraints::Solution>&, swift::OptionSet<swift::TypeCheckExprFlags, unsigned int>) + 732
9  swift                    0x000000010b2c87ba swift::TypeChecker::typeCheckExpression(swift::Expr*&, swift::DeclContext*, swift::Type, swift::ContextualTypePurpose, swift::OptionSet<swift::TypeCheckExprFlags, unsigned int>, swift::ExprTypeCheckListener*) + 474
10 swift                    0x000000010b26e366 (anonymous namespace)::FailureDiagnosis::typeCheckChildIndependently(swift::Expr*, swift::Type, swift::ContextualTypePurpose, swift::OptionSet<TCCFlags, unsigned int>) + 806
11 swift                    0x000000010b26c2cf swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::FailureDiagnosis, bool, void, void, void, void, void>::visit(swift::Expr*) + 4863
12 swift                    0x000000010b2665c0 swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::diagnoseFailureForExpr(swift::Expr*) + 576
13 swift                    0x000000010b2693cf swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::salvage(llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::constraints::Solution>&, swift::Expr*) + 143
14 swift                    0x000000010b2c3bfc swift::TypeChecker::solveForExpression(swift::Expr*&, swift::DeclContext*, swift::Type, swift::FreeTypeVariableBinding, swift::ExprTypeCheckListener*, swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem&, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::constraints::Solution>&, swift::OptionSet<swift::TypeCheckExprFlags, unsigned int>) + 732
15 swift                    0x000000010b2c87ba swift::TypeChecker::typeCheckExpression(swift::Expr*&, swift::DeclContext*, swift::Type, swift::ContextualTypePurpose, swift::OptionSet<swift::TypeCheckExprFlags, unsigned int>, swift::ExprTypeCheckListener*) + 474
16 swift                    0x000000010b26e366 (anonymous namespace)::FailureDiagnosis::typeCheckChildIndependently(swift::Expr*, swift::Type, swift::ContextualTypePurpose, swift::OptionSet<TCCFlags, unsigned int>) + 806
17 swift                    0x000000010b26f305 std::__1::__function::__func<(anonymous namespace)::FailureDiagnosis::visitExpr(swift::Expr*)::$_9, std::__1::allocator<(anonymous namespace)::FailureDiagnosis::visitExpr(swift::Expr*)::$_9>, void (swift::Expr*)>::operator()(swift::Expr*&&) + 37
18 swift                    0x000000010b3c8547 swift::Expr::forEachChildExpr(std::__1::function<void (swift::Expr*)> const&)::ChildWalker::walkToExprPre(swift::Expr*) + 39
19 swift                    0x000000010b36dfa2 (anonymous namespace)::Traversal::visit(swift::Expr*) + 2610
20 swift                    0x000000010b36cc85 swift::Expr::walk(swift::ASTWalker&) + 53
21 swift                    0x000000010b3c61fc swift::Expr::forEachChildExpr(std::__1::function<void (swift::Expr*)> const&) + 44
22 swift                    0x000000010b26c098 swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::FailureDiagnosis, bool, void, void, void, void, void>::visit(swift::Expr*) + 4296
23 swift                    0x000000010b2665c0 swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::diagnoseFailureForExpr(swift::Expr*) + 576
24 swift                    0x000000010b2693cf swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::salvage(llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::constraints::Solution>&, swift::Expr*) + 143
25 swift                    0x000000010b2c3bfc swift::TypeChecker::solveForExpression(swift::Expr*&, swift::DeclContext*, swift::Type, swift::FreeTypeVariableBinding, swift::ExprTypeCheckListener*, swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem&, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::constraints::Solution>&, swift::OptionSet<swift::TypeCheckExprFlags, unsigned int>) + 732
26 swift                    0x000000010b2c87ba swift::TypeChecker::typeCheckExpression(swift::Expr*&, swift::DeclContext*, swift::Type, swift::ContextualTypePurpose, swift::OptionSet<swift::TypeCheckExprFlags, unsigned int>, swift::ExprTypeCheckListener*) + 474
27 swift                    0x000000010b26e366 (anonymous namespace)::FailureDiagnosis::typeCheckChildIndependently(swift::Expr*, swift::Type, swift::ContextualTypePurpose, swift::OptionSet<TCCFlags, unsigned int>) + 806
28 swift                    0x000000010b266583 swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::diagnoseFailureForExpr(swift::Expr*) + 515
29 swift                    0x000000010b2693cf swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::salvage(llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::constraints::Solution>&, swift::Expr*) + 143
30 swift                    0x000000010b2c3bfc swift::TypeChecker::solveForExpression(swift::Expr*&, swift::DeclContext*, swift::Type, swift::FreeTypeVariableBinding, swift::ExprTypeCheckListener*, swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem&, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::constraints::Solution>&, swift::OptionSet<swift::TypeCheckExprFlags, unsigned int>) + 732
31 swift                    0x000000010b2c87ba swift::TypeChecker::typeCheckExpression(swift::Expr*&, swift::DeclContext*, swift::Type, swift::ContextualTypePurpose, swift::OptionSet<swift::TypeCheckExprFlags, unsigned int>, swift::ExprTypeCheckListener*) + 474
32 swift                    0x000000010b31ae5b swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::StmtChecker, void, swift::Stmt*, void, void, void, void>::visit(swift::Stmt*) + 411
33 swift                    0x000000010b3199b2 swift::TypeChecker::typeCheckFunctionBodyUntil(swift::FuncDecl*, swift::SourceLoc) + 370
34 swift                    0x000000010b31a2d3 swift::TypeChecker::typeCheckAbstractFunctionBody(swift::AbstractFunctionDecl*) + 179
35 swift                    0x000000010b2b43b2 typeCheckFunctionsAndExternalDecls(swift::TypeChecker&) + 242
36 swift                    0x000000010b2b50f7 swift::performTypeChecking(swift::SourceFile&, swift::TopLevelContext&, swift::OptionSet<swift::TypeCheckingFlags, unsigned int>, unsigned int) + 1831
37 swift                    0x000000010b104224 swift::CompilerInstance::performSema() + 4340
38 swift                    0x000000010ad3b605 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&) + 741
39 swift                    0x000000010ad3b10a frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*) + 2682
40 swift                    0x000000010ad37797 main + 2247
41 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff99c895c9 start + 1
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/SpeakerDetailsViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/AboutUsViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/AttendeeCell.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/ConfirmNewProfileImageViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/SurveyViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/NotificationsTableViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/SponsorWebsiteViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/FavoritesTableViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/AgendaViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/AppDelegate.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/Sponsor.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/CustomNavController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/StickyNotification.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/MoreInfoViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/TravelVC.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/SponsorsTableViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/SpeakerCell.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/BasicNavController.swift -primary-file /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/Event.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/PublicConstants.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/Attendee.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/Conference.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/ConfInfoViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/DBQuestion.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/TravelBusiness.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/MyAcountPrefsTableViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/PeopleViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/EventDetailsViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/SideMenuTableVC.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/Speaker.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/NotificationManager.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/QRViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/ConfListTableViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/DiscussionBoard.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/ENSideMenu.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/Session.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/QRWebViewController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/ManTabBarController.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/ObjectManager.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/ColoredSegmentButton.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/DBManager.swift /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/ENSideMenuNavigationController.swift -target x86_64-apple-ios8.0 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk -I /Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI -F /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf -F /Users/satre/Downloads/parse-library-1 -enable-testing -g -import-objc-header /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf-Bridging-Header.h -module-cache-path /Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -D COCOAPODS -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Intermediates/STSI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/STSI.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Intermediates/STSI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/STSI.build/STSI-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Intermediates/STSI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/STSI.build/STSI-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Intermediates/STSI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/STSI.build/STSI-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Intermediates/STSI.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Intermediates/STSI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/STSI.build/STSI-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Intermediates/STSI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/STSI.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Intermediates/STSI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/STSI.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc -working-directory/Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI -emit-module-doc-path /Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Intermediates/STSI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/STSI.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Event~partial.swiftdoc -Onone -module-name STSI -emit-module-path /Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Intermediates/STSI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/STSI.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Event~partial.swiftmodule -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Intermediates/STSI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/STSI.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Event.dia -emit-dependencies-path /Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Intermediates/STSI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/STSI.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Event.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Intermediates/STSI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/STSI.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Event.swiftdeps -o /Users/satre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/STSI-gpjzpccyzlbzmdciwcbqdfguddto/Build/Intermediates/STSI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/STSI.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Event.o 
1.  While type-checking 'fetchSpeakersForEvent' at /Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/Event.swift:220:5
2.  While type-checking expression at [/Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/Event.swift:228:9 - line:256:10] RangeText="query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (speakerObjects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print( error )
                return
            }



            let theSpeakers: [Speaker] = speakerObjects!.map({ (aSpeaker: AnyObject) -> Speaker in
                let theSpeaker = aSpeaker as! Speaker

                //Don't want to hog up the main thread, so dispatch to queue
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), { () -> Void in
                    for someSpeaker in ObjectManager.speakers {
                        if someSpeaker.objectId == theSpeaker.objectId {
                            if !someSpeaker.eventsForSpeaker.contains(self) {
                                someSpeaker.eventsForSpeaker.append(self)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(DataConstants.newSpeakerEventRelationships, object: nil)
                })


                return theSpeaker
            })

            self.speakersForEvent = theSpeakers
        })"
3.  While type-checking expression at [/Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/Event.swift:228:9 - line:256:10] RangeText="query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (speakerObjects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print( error )
                return
            }



            let theSpeakers: [Speaker] = speakerObjects!.map({ (aSpeaker: AnyObject) -> Speaker in
                let theSpeaker = aSpeaker as! Speaker

                //Don't want to hog up the main thread, so dispatch to queue
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), { () -> Void in
                    for someSpeaker in ObjectManager.speakers {
                        if someSpeaker.objectId == theSpeaker.objectId {
                            if !someSpeaker.eventsForSpeaker.contains(self) {
                                someSpeaker.eventsForSpeaker.append(self)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(DataConstants.newSpeakerEventRelationships, object: nil)
                })


                return theSpeaker
            })

            self.speakersForEvent = theSpeakers
        })"
4.  While type-checking expression at [/Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/Event.swift:228:9 - line:256:10] RangeText="query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (speakerObjects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print( error )
                return
            }



            let theSpeakers: [Speaker] = speakerObjects!.map({ (aSpeaker: AnyObject) -> Speaker in
                let theSpeaker = aSpeaker as! Speaker

                //Don't want to hog up the main thread, so dispatch to queue
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), { () -> Void in
                    for someSpeaker in ObjectManager.speakers {
                        if someSpeaker.objectId == theSpeaker.objectId {
                            if !someSpeaker.eventsForSpeaker.contains(self) {
                                someSpeaker.eventsForSpeaker.append(self)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(DataConstants.newSpeakerEventRelationships, object: nil)
                })


                return theSpeaker
            })

            self.speakersForEvent = theSpeakers
        })"
5.  While type-checking expression at [/Users/satre/Developer/Projects/STSI/MedConf/Event.swift:228:49 - line:256:9] RangeText="{ (speakerObjects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print( error )
                return
            }



            let theSpeakers: [Speaker] = speakerObjects!.map({ (aSpeaker: AnyObject) -> Speaker in
                let theSpeaker = aSpeaker as! Speaker

                //Don't want to hog up the main thread, so dispatch to queue
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), { () -> Void in
                    for someSpeaker in ObjectManager.speakers {
                        if someSpeaker.objectId == theSpeaker.objectId {
                            if !someSpeaker.eventsForSpeaker.contains(self) {
                                someSpeaker.eventsForSpeaker.append(self)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(DataConstants.newSpeakerEventRelationships, object: nil)
                })


                return theSpeaker
            })

            self.speakersForEvent = theSpeakers
        }"
```

What is the cause of this fault? I see that it has something to do with type checking, but I can't figure out the cause. I am also using the latest version of the Parse SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method signature for PFQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock has changed. Refer: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/280

Replace `(speakerObjects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in` with `(speakerObjects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in`